# NSCalendarUnit flag to set all flags

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

The following will create an `NSDateComponents` object containing `day` and `weekday` but not `hour`:

```
var today = NSDate()
var gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
var flags: NSCalendarUnit = .DayCalendarUnit | .WeekdayCalendarUnit
var components = gregorian.components(flags, fromDate: today)

// valid
components.day
components.weekday
// invalid
components.hour
```

In order to have `hour`, I would have to `|`-in the `.HourCalendarUnit` like this:

```
flags = flags | .HourCalendarUnit
```

Is there a flag to specify all flags? Or do I just have to manually `|` them all in if I want an `NSDateComponents` to have them all?

Alternatively, and ideally, I would like to just be able to say `today.hour` without using `NSDateComponents` at all. Does such a class exist?

Comment: Note: .DayCalendarUnit, .WeekdayCalendarUnit and .HourCalendarUnit are deprecated and should be changed for .CalendarUnitDay, .CalendarUnitWeekday, CalendarUnitHour and so on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSCalendarUnit` can be initialized with an `UInt`, so this gives you 
all possible components:

```
var today = NSDate()
var gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
var flags = NSCalendarUnit(UInt.max)
var components = gregorian.components(flags, fromDate: today)
```

A `today.hour` method does not exist because the calculation cannot be done without
knowing the time zone to use for the conversion.

**Update for Swift 2:**

```
let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let flags = NSCalendarUnit(rawValue: UInt.max)
```

Comment: I disagree that time zone is a limitation. `NSDate` already uses the local time zone by default. You can see this in the printed preview in swift playgrounds. It could just use a default timezone and default gregorian calendar. I know it isn't impossible because I am writing my own `Date` class that does it.

Comment: @ChrisRedford: Yes, I did not express myself well. In the Foundation frameworks, NSDate represents just an absolute point in time, without any knowledge of time zone, days, month etc. All calendrical calculation are done with NSCalendar (which is more or less a wrapper to the ICU calendar functions). There are also utility methods such as descriptionWithCalendarFormat(), but no hour() method.

Comment: You can get only the hour also using descriptionWithCalendarFormat() but it will return String format %H (00-23) or %I (01-12)

Comment: I read it and I understood what you said but it is easy to implement an hour() function and there is no need to use TimeZone

Comment: Anyone figure out how to do this in Swift 3.0 yet? Just did myself. ```NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: UInt.max)```

Comment: @AndrewAnthonyGerst: You can bridge `Calendar` back to `NSCalendar`, so this seems to work: `(gregorian as NSCalendar).components(NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: UInt.max), from: today)`. – There may be a nicer method though.